# Rolling div - css with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to understand the rolling effect [this web site](http://www.statek-psychologia.pl/) has.

I am new to web development, I would like to know if it is just css or it has help from javascript/jQuery...
If yes, except the `<div id="rotator" ...` which javascript file should I pay attention to?

I am talking about the rolling effect when the user selects each menu item, START, O NAS, OFERTA etc...

Comment: the general approach i'd use is to open the dev tools in chrome with `F12` and do a file search `CTRL+SHIFT+F` for the string `rotator`. You will see that the site uses a combination of jQuery and CSS to achieve its effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses CSS animation, changing background image position of the containing `div` using transition. The image itself has that angled line in it.

```
.col-4-set > li .note {
-o-transition-property: background-position;
-o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
-ms-transition-property: background-position;
-ms-transition-duration: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition-property: background-position;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
-moz-transition-property: background-position;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
transition-property: background-position;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
background: transparent url('images/box_hover.jpg') no-repeat -600px -600px;
position: absolute;
left: -1px;
top: -1px;
width: 184px;
height: 222px;
padding: 9px 18px;
}
```

Some further reading on easing background transitions:

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/